# error 'The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.'

Tags: plugin-development

I am getting this error from a small plugin I've created.

> The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.

Code:

```
/**
Plugin name : Live Page Counter
**/
function live_page_counter(){
    global $wpdb;
    $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );
    echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";
}
add_shortcode('counterhit', 'live_page_counter');
```

I don't know where I am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try without spaces beetween `Plugin name` and `:`

```
Plugin name: Live Page Counter
```